# Sprite Kit crashes when presenting scene

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

My spriteKit game crashes when you transition to a new view and touch anything in that view. I use a scrollView in my original view and have found that it is the problem (it works when its not there) any help would be wonderful :)

I add the scrollView here

```
CGAffineTransform verticalFlip = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,-1);
scrollViewMenu = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:self.frame]; 
scrollViewMenu.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
scrollViewMenu.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width,                                 scrollBackGround1.frame.size.height+scrollBackGround2.frame.size.height);
scrollViewMenu.transform = verticalFlip;
scrollViewMenu.hidden = true;
[self.view addSubview:scrollViewMenu];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:scrollViewMenu.panGestureRecognizer];
scrollViewMenu.delegate = self;
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:scrollViewMenu];
```

And I transition to the other scene with this

```
JMLevel01 *level = [[JMLevel01 alloc]initWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width,    self.view.bounds.size.height)];
[self.view presentScene:level];
```

And here is my willMoveFromView

```
[super willMoveFromView:view];  
[self.view removeGestureRecognizer:scrollViewMenu.panGestureRecognizer];
scrollViewMenu = nil;
```

Thank You!

Comment: What is the stack trace?

Comment: How would I find that out? @possen

Comment: @JeremyMackey  In the console of Xcode, when you run your app, and then it crashes.  There will be logs saying what the crash was, and will probably point you in the right direction to start looking.

Comment: All that appears in the console is "(lldb)". And I get a "EXE_BAD_ACCESS" @Gilderman

Comment: Look at the chain of calls and see if you can see what its. You can also paste the contents of the thread that crashed here, if you can't figure it out yourself.

Comment: I don't know how to do that either. The log was just that statement @possen thank you for your responses

Comment: If you are in Xcode at the point of the crash you can see the stack on the left hand side. Command-6 should bring it up if it is not already there. You will see a list of threads. Select them all then copy and paste the result here. Sorry don't always check Stackoverflow so my answers might not be really fast. To debug yourself, click on each line and you can see what function called what and you can see the variables in the function at the time of the crash. Check them to make sure they look like what you expect.